# Django - Displaying Images in Templates

Tags: django, image, function, view, django-views

I have a Django Website and I am currently working on a delete view that has to be a function-based view for later use. I need to display a name and an image in the template of the data I am deleting at that moment. I had it working as a class-based view but now I need it to be a function-based delete view. The code below works and displays the name but when it comes to the image(which is an image field so I cant just type in a URL in the src) it just displays that little miscellaneous image box on the screen and not my actual image. In the templates, if I put {{ image.url }} it displays nothing. **How can I get and image to display in the template from a specific pk in a function-based view.**

views.py

```
def deleterepo(request, pk):
context = {}
context['name'] = Add_Repo.objects.values_list('name', flat='True').filter(user=request.user).get(pk=pk)
context['image'] = Add_Repo.objects.values_list('image', flat='True').filter(user=request.user).get(pk=pk)

obj = get_object_or_404(Add_Repo, pk=pk)

if request.method == "POST":
    obj.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/front_page/sheets/")

return render(request, "sheets/repo/delete_repo.html", context)



{{ name }}
<img src="{{ image }}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of  using `values_list` you can just pass the `add_repo` instance to the template.

```
context = {} 
obj = get_object_or_404(Add_Repo, pk=pk)
context["repo"] = obj
```

Now in the template:

```
Name: {{repo.name}}
<img src="{{ repo.image.url }}"/>
```